# Using multiple else if statements in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am a beginning programmer and I am creating my first website.
I haver a problem with an else if statement in an function in JavaScript. The problem is that my website always seems to go for the first else if answer, even if its not true. this is the function:

```js
if (600 <= regenid < 614) {
  var tempcijfer = 1
} else if (gevoelstempc < 0.1) {
  var tempcijfer = 1
} else if (0.1 < gevoelstempc < 6.5) {
  var tempcijfer = 2
} else if (6.5 < gevoelstempc < 10.9) {
  var tempcijfer = 3
} else if (10.9 < gevoelstempc < 12.9) {
  var tempcijfer = 4
} else if (12.9 < gevoelstempc < 15.9) {
  var tempcijfer = 5
} else if (15.9 < gevoelstempc < 17.5) {
  var tempcijfer = 6
} else if (17.5 < gevoelstempc < 19.5) {
  var tempcijfer = 7
} else if (19.5 < gevoelstempc < 21.1) {
  var tempcijfer = 8
} else if (21.1 < gevoelstempc < 22.9) {
  var tempcijfer = 9
} else if (22.9 < gevoelstempc < 25.2) {
  var tempcijfer = 10
} else if (25.2 < gevoelstempc < 27.9) {
  var tempcijfer = 9
} else if (27.9 < gevoelstempc < 30.1) {
  var tempcijfer = 8
} else if (30.1 < gevoelstempc < 32.9) {
  var tempcijfer = 7
} else if (32.9 < gevoelstempc < 34.9) {
  var tempcijfer = 6
} else if (34.9 < gevoelstempc < 37.1) {
  var tempcijfer = 5
} else if (37.1 < gevoelstempc < 39.1) {
  var tempcijfer = 4
} else if (39.1 < gevoelstempc < 40.5) {
  var tempcijfer = 3
} else if (40.5 < gevoelstempc < 41.5) {
  var tempcijfer = 2
} else if (gevoelstempc > 41, 5) {
  var tempcijfer = 1
}
```

`tempcijfer` always seems to become `1` even if `gevoelstempc` is bigger than `6.5`)
How do I solve this?

Comment: `( 600<=regenid<614 )` that condition is incorrect. I guess that what you want to say is that `( 600<=something && regenid<614 )` ?

Comment: For starters, this is JavaScript not HTML.  (Makes it important when running the code snippet.)  Aside from that, in this example variables like `regenid` and `gevoelstempc` are never defined, so the example doesn't demonstrate the problem.  You also have a typo on your last `if` condition.  And you never use the `tempcijfer` variable so where/how are you even observing the result?  Ultimately, whatever `if` block was executed, that condition was true.  Guaranteed.  Perhaps you could provide an example which demonstrates what you're seeing?

Comment: yes, do I have to do this every time I want to say something is inbetween to numbers? @_Dalorzo

Comment: @RienenArdiet: Correct.  There's no "between" operator really.  Being between two values is a combination of being greater than one value and less than another.  You can combine as many conditions as you want into a single boolean statement, as long as each component of that statement itself resolves to a boolean.

Comment: @David I have everything defined but I didnt copy and paste it into the code here, because it would be very long and unclear. Where do you see the typo btw?

Comment: @RienenArdiet: `41,5` was probably supposed to be `41.5`.  As for being "very long and unclear", that's exactly where bugs hide.  If the code is too difficult to understand, simplify it.  Reduce the problem space.  As a general rule of thumb, if you can't produce a complete example demonstrating the problem then the problem probably isn't what/where you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how if works. You are putting two operators on the same comparison. I think that what you trying to do with `if( 600<=regenid<614 )` is if(600 <= regenid && regenid < 614). The operator `&&` means "and".

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the condition of if statement like that, you must use operators like && ( for AND operator) and || ( for OR operator)

So your code will be like this:

```
   if ( regenid >= 600 && regenid < 614 ){ var tempcijfer= 1 }
```

and the same for the other conditions in your code.